# update two array elements using setState

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple list of users

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    { name: 'john', order: 0 },
    { name: 'mary', order: 1 },
    { name: 'Lou', order: 200 }
]);
```

I want to set order = 40 to the first element and order = 12 to the second element in the same operation

```
setUsers(...users, ?, ?)
```

Comment: how many elements are there going to be? and is the field like the `order` here (numerical and ascending in order)?

Comment: multiple elements... (I only added 2 for brevity) order can be any number

Comment: and you want to order it in what way? ascending order?

Comment: just want to set any value I want for the order key. im planning to use this when Im done with a drag and drop operation to sync the state

Comment: so you have an array of values for the order and you want to merge that with this state overriding the order key?

Comment: yes. something like that. I have a list of users I want to reorder with drag and drop and save the updated order in each element

Comment: can you make a codesandbox or something that replicates the error you're having? will be a lot easier to help build it if theres something to start off of.

Comment: Thinking away from arrays (and away from OP question) for your use case, I suggest using an object for the state while indexing them by some id (or name depending on what you identify each user with). It'll help make update operations cleaner and in the same oepration.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of setState callback and array destructuring to update your state

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([
  { name: "john", order: 0 },
  { name: "mary", order: 1 },
  { name: "Lou", order: 200 }
]);

setUsers(([first, second, ...rest]) => [
  { ...first, order: 40 },
  { ...second, order: 12 },
  ...rest
]);
```

Comment: Was about to paste same :P.

Answer (score 1):

Since React's state should be immutable, you would need to do deep cloning (either through a library such as **lodash**, or manually).

I recommend using [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) which not only makes things easier, but also is much more efficient than creating deep clones:

```js
import produce from "immer";

const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    { name: 'john', order: 0 },
    { name: 'mary', order: 1 },
    { name: 'Lou', order: 200 }
]);

setUsers(produce(users, draftUsers => {
    draftUsers[0].order = 12;
    draftUsers[1].order = 40;
});
```

Voilà, the beauty of this is that the object `Lou` remains unchanged, hence internally, `immer` won't recreate it.

Be careful to avoid *shallow* cloning:

```js
const newUsers = [...users];  // new copies of the user objects... right?

newUsers[0].order = 12 ;
console.log(users[0].order);  // -> 12 <-  oops! We mutated the state >_<
```

Answer (score 0):

## you can do it easily using the Index or add mew field 'ID' like here:

use a filter to match index/id and then change your object item. link: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-grass-4nnvv)

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    { name: 'john', order: 0 },
    { name: 'mary', order: 1 },
    { name: 'Lou', order: 200 }
]);


const changeUserData = (index, amount) => {
  let _users = users.map((user, i) => {
    if(i===index) {
      user.order = 40
    }
    return user;
  })

  setUsers(_users);
} 


<ul style={{textAlign: 'left'}}>
    {
    users.map((user, index)=> (
      <li key={index}>Name: {user.name}, Order: {user.order}</li>
    ))
  }
</ul>

<button onClick={(e)=>changeUserData(0, 40)}>Click to update</button>
```

Maybe it helps to solve your problem,

**Thank you**

Comment: Mutating a `user` object from useState is not good practice. I suggest creating a new user object to avoid assigning `user.order` to 40.